# SigmaJS: Get node labels to wrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, cytoscape.js, sigma.js

I'd like to know how to get node labels in SigmaJS to wrap. Adding `\n` to the labels doesn't work. For example, in the image below, I'd like the text to wrap to a new line after "double-strand"

Here's an example of adding nodes to a SigmaJS graph (version 1.2), where `NODES` is an array of node attributes:

```js
let graph = {nodes: []};

NODES.forEach(function (node) {
    graph.nodes.push({ 
        id:  node.id,
        label: node.label,
        x: node.x * nodeXAdj,
        y: -node.y * nodeYAdj,
        size: node.size,
        type: node.type,
        color: node.color,
        borderColor: node.borderColor,
    });
});

let s = new sigma({graph: graph});
```

[image]